# azure tentant id null when running in the unit test framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication, azure, integration-testing

I have a azure mvc application that has some code that involves authentication against azure active directory. 
I want to write som integration test. The problem i am facing is that some of my production code calls claim types which are not available when i run in the unit test framework. For example the line below:

> ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: How are you writing the tests?  You can just mock out the call to authenticate and have it return a test-specific identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am with the Azure AD team. Most of our partners and customers use a test Azure AD instance for testing and staging. I recommend that you do the same. To automate for test automation you will want to silently acquire a token - for that I recommend that you use the Resource Owner Password Grant OAuth flow in your test cases - a sample console application is here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Yes of course, thats not a problem i will use config overrides to use the correct Azure AD instance. i looked at the github sample project. if i understand it correctly i need to register my unit test project as a native application in the specifc Azure AD instance that i want to use for the tests?

Comment: finally got some time to test this. but im stuck now:

`authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(todoListResourceId, clientId);
// always fails with the exception : Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken. Why? `

 `//but then in the catch block i can access the token with: authContext.AcquireToken(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc);`

but tentantid and other needed claimtypes are still null? 

Of cource i have replaced all config values with my unit test project and i have registrered the application in my tentant

Comment: AcquireTokenSilent tries to get a token silently using the oauth code grant flow - it is expected to fail in your case as the user hasn't authenticated. For your unit test you must use the oauth password credential flow (acquire token with user credential - the one that's working)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation then i skip AcquireTokenSilent. but how can i solve the main problem with the claimtypes?

Comment: Hmmm. No claim should be missing. Can you trap the access token using fiddler, decode it using https://authnauthz.com/OAuth/DecodeJWTToken and paste the decoded content here? Also please add the unit test code here.

Comment: i have put "is not empty" where there is some organisation data. first part of the body:
`
`{
  "aud": "is not empty",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e7509563-70bf-4afe-aa3b-cbab084f345b/",
  "iat": 1421622458,
  "nbf": 1421622458,
  "exp": 1421626358,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "tid": "e7509563-70bf-4afe-aa3b-cbab084f345b",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],`

Comment: `second part of the body:
 "oid": "941fa8ee-0c35-4c82-b826-e69c99db8b17",
  "upn": "is not empty",
  "sub": "ajYewvkfY-ySjMB5J_KaMRpPRpk8w0NRxpxUd-N0SVI",
  "given_name": "is not empty",
  "family_name": "is not empty",
  "name": "is not empty",
  "unique_name": "is not empty",
  "appid": "f329f04d-3845-46e1-9a68-903206f2113f",
  "appidacr": "0",
  "scp": "user_impersonation",
  "acr": "1"
}`

Comment: the header:
`JWT Header:
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "kriMPdmBvx68skT8-mPAB3BseeA"
}`

Comment: here are the authentication code for the unit test:
`AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            UserCredential uc = new UserCredential("mail, "pw");

            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            result = authContext.AcquireToken(myMvcAppReourceId, thisNativeAppClientId, uc);

this is null...Claim objectIdentifier = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");`

Comment: Sorry I had missed this. Thanks for the ping. David, your code is getting back a token but the claims principal or claims identity is not being set. For that you must use the JWT token handler (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate the token and set the claims principal. There are many samples on the net.

Comment: Thans for your answer! i cannot find any examples on how to this?

Comment: its now working with the JWT token handler! i extratct the claims with the JWT token handler and then add them to the claims. Thanks for all your help Dushyant!

Comment: No problem David. Go ahead and mark it as the answer. Thanks